# How to wake up a computer over lan?

Tags: windows-7, power-management, wake-on-lan

I got a "server" in the basement hosting music and media files. 
It is nice to shut it down without having to go down there, via remote desktop or the "shutdown -i" command etc.

But is there someway of waking it up? It should not wake up on other kinds of traffic, just when I specifically want it to.

The computer runs win7 ultimate, and motherboard is 2-3 year old MSI, if it makes a difference.

What choices do I have to achive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the BIOS there should be a option on enable Wake On Lan (WOL). Once this is enabled, you can send a WOL "packet" to the network card using, for example, AMD Magic Packet, or other Magic Packet Utilites.

Comment: Additionally, some router firmware has WOL support. In Tomato you can send WOL packets from the router config interface.

Comment: I've been googling the solutions to suggested, and this seems to be exactly what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I've used the tools from [Depicus](http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/) with success.  As tombull89 has noted, the computer must have it enabled first.